# javascript object element bug

Tags: javascript, object

I have this javascript object,

```
console.log(object.response);
console.log(object.response.imageUID);
```

gives me:

```
{"id":138,"imageUID":"image-aa0dce87-0261-44ef-8377-d897a996f4b1"}  
undefined
```

What went wrong?

Comment: Is `response` a string or another object?

Comment: response is an object

Comment: Try console.log(object.response["imageUID"]);

Comment: @blackops: no won't do, still undefined.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.parse(object.response).imageUID);`

Comment: @blackops How would that help?

Comment: in Chrome at least,I noticed that if I output objects using `console.log`, they do not show properties that existed when the `console.log` method was called but they show updated properties that were set later. This probably happens because the browser keeps a reference to the object for display, I do not know.

Comment: @Ian: Depending on how you create your "obj" you can have an array that looks like an object but just has strings for indexes but is type array. The only difference is {} and (). Chrome will put the word object in front of your object and not in front of the array when you console log it.

Comment: @blackops That literally makes no sense. An array is an object. An object has properties. You can get an object's properties with dot notation or bracket notation. The only reason to use bracket notation is if the key isn't a valid identifier or if the key is stored in a variable

Comment: ...so `response` **is** a string not an object. Careful how you interpret `console.log` output. In Chrome, you can very easily see the difference as an object would have been output as *`Object { id: 138, ... }`* and a string as simply `{ id: 138, ... }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seemed the issue was that your response was a stringified object - so it probably looked like:

```
var response = '{"id":138,"imageUID":"image-aa0dce87-0261-44ef-8377-d897a996f4b1"}';
```

In order to access the properties you must first parse that string into an object:

```
var responseObj = JSON.parse(response);
```

Now you can access the properties:

```
var imageUID = responseObj.imageUID;
```